# ViewPager and Fragment Pager adapter implementation

Tags: android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

So I am trying to implement sliding views/fragments using viewpager and fragment pager adapter. convert_home is my main xml file that has android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip and

temperature.xml and velocity.xml are my two other views. I have no clue where I am going wrong. THE APP IS CRASHING (on load)

```
package app.converto;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConverTo extends FragmentActivity {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        setContentView(R.layout.converto_home);  
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.converto_home, menu);
        return true;
    }





    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();  

                return fragment;

            case 1:
                        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();  
                return fragment2;


            }
            defaultFragment fragment3 = new defaultFragment();  
            return fragment3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
//
//        @Override
//        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
//            switch (position) {
//                case 0: return getString(R.string.velocity);
//                case 1: return getString(R.string.temperature);
//                case 2: return getString(R.string.distance);
//            }
//            return null;
//        }
    }

        public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment1(){
            }
             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature, container, false);

                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature, container, false);  
                 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sample);  
                 textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment2(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.velocity, container, false);

                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature, container, false);  
                 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sample);  
                 textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class defaultFragment extends Fragment{
            public defaultFragment(){
            }//end constructor

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature, container, false);




                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature, container, false);  
                 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sample);  
                 textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }//end oncreate




        }//end default fragment

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm everything seems ok, what exactly is the problem you are facing? Can you be more specific?

EDIT: 
Oh I think I know what is your problem I didn't see it the first time. In your ConvertTo class you set the adapter of mViewPager before you initialize it. So change your OnCreate method to this: (Let me know if that was the problem)

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    setContentView(R.layout.converto_home);  

    // Initialize it first otherwise it stays null
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 

    //Then you set the adapter
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);  


}
```

Comment: Oh Sorry about that. The apps crashes on loading.

Comment: Are you using more than one activity? if you are using more than one activity in your app make sure you include them in your manifest file ... sorry but I think your code is fine I feel the crash might be caused for other reason than your code maybe is the sdk you are using idk

Comment: Just one activity
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ConverTo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conver_to" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is help to any one but I've been playing with the above example ( as a noob to Android programming ) and added in 3 more fragment sections and re-enabled the menu for 6 options. I've yet to test the fragments out my self and place content in but I'm hoping that if some one else is where I am it may benefit too as there seems to be little documentation on the work flow of the SDK examples. This means it can take a little longer to understand experience.

You will need to have some stings setup for the menu names and have your layouts also ready too.

```
package uk.co.letscommunicate.manx.central;
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658365/viewpager-and-fragment-pager-adapter-implementation

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
     * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
     * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }



    //unknown may be tab swipe
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
   }
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }
    // unknown    





    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                return fragment1;

            case 1:
                Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();  
                return fragment2;            

            case 2:
                Fragment3 fragment3 = new Fragment3();  
                return fragment3;    

            case 3:
                Fragment4 fragment4 = new Fragment4();  
                return fragment4;    

            case 4:
                Fragment5 fragment5 = new Fragment5();  
                return fragment5; 

            case 5:
                Fragment6 fragment6 = new Fragment6();  
                return fragment6;
            }            
            DefaultFragment DefaultFragment = new DefaultFragment();  
            return DefaultFragment;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1);
                case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2);
                case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3);
                case 3: return getString(R.string.title_section4);
                case 4: return getString(R.string.title_section5);
                case 5: return getString(R.string.title_section6);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

        public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment1(){
            }
             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {





                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment2(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment3(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class Fragment4 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment4(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }        

        public static class Fragment5 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment5(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class Fragment6 extends Fragment{
            public Fragment6(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }

        }

        public static class DefaultFragment extends Fragment{
            public DefaultFragment(){
            }

             @Override  
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
             } 
             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {



                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailframent, container, false);  
                 //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);  
                 //textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
                 return view;
             }
             //end on create

        }//end default fragment

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The textview was causing the app to crash. I didnt declare it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);        
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Swap the above two lines so it looks like:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```